# Masking i386 entries in `aptitude`?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I have a 64 bits system, and usually use `aptitude` to select and install packages.  For packages that comes both in a 64 bits and 32 bits version, two versions of the package are listed:

```
   packagename
   packagemame:i386
```

Often (usually?) both the 64 bits and 32 bits version cannot be installed simultaneously - installing one, "breaks" the other...

Is there a way to get `aptitude` to hide one of the two types - eg. hide the 32 bits :i386 version of packages?  For example some configuration option to select either one or the other...

I've tried Menu (C-T)->Search->Limit Display...  But I didn't know quite what to put there...  ":i386" yielded nothing... "i386" yielded just a few packages that included "i386" in the package-name - the ":i386"-part is obviously not part of the name.  And in any case, I would want to limit the display to packages *not* containing ":i386"...

The reason I ask, is because of Tasks...  Here all the packages needed to make for example a LAMP-server or a Mail-server are grouped together - but unfortunately both the 32 bits and the 64 bits version.  So if I for example tries to add all the packages that makes up a LAMP-server by pressing **+** with "LAMP" selected; then both the 32 and 64 bits version of each package are selected, and thus "break" each other.

Comment: That is a VERY GOOD question however I haven't seen any answers (or previous questions) on the subject in my short 3 months here.

Comment: For pure command line searches, it seems to be possible to specify a generic apt-config option e.g. `aptitude -o Apt::Architectures::="amd64" search packagename` - I'm not sure if invoking the TUI with such an option helps though?

Comment: @steeldriver Not sure about ubuntu but at least in Debian this works beautifully with `aptitude -o Apt::Architectures::="amd64"`. Thanks a lot. You should make that an answer.